# NHibernate exception "Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'."

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate

I am getting the folloinwg error from NHibernate:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Session is closed! Object name: 'ISession'.
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.ErrorIfClosed()
   at NHibernate.Impl.AbstractSessionImpl.CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireSave(SaveOrUpdateEvent event)
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Save(Object obj)
```

I am using NHibernate in .net windows service.
 I am not able to trace the excact problem for the exception. This exception occurs very often.
Any one can help me on this to fix this exception?

nrk

Comment: Yes.. I am opening the connection. Actually i am doing a file import application, in that I am doing record insertion batch-wise (200) with session and commiting the session and those records are available in DB also,, but after 2 or 3 batches it's giving this exception. I am not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says - it looks like you are trying to save an object when your ISession is closed.  Are you sure you are opening it?  Or perhaps it is being closed prematurely?

Update:
Have you checked the NHibernate Logs?

Comment: looks similar like that, but making cascading= none fixed the issue.

Comment: Glad you got it working. If I were you though, I'd be sure to take a look at the nhibernate log4net logs, to maybe get some more info in whats going on, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743323/nhibernate-enabling-log4net

Comment: @vapcguy See above link

Comment: @UpTheCreek - Thanks -- in other words, ensure you're logging them yourself, using log4NET, or other.

Answer (score 6):

I am guessing you are wrapping your session in a using construct more than once, something like below. Can you post some of your session usage code?

HTH,
Berryl

Wrong - the session is closed after the first using construct:

```
using(var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
using(var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(){
    ... do something
    tx.Commit();
}


using(var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession()
using(var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(){
    ... do something else
}
```

Better- the session is closed after it's work is done

```
var session = _sessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();

using(var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(){
    ... do something
    tx.Commit();
}


using(var tx = _session.BeginTransaction(){
    ... do something else
    tx.Commit()
}
session.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

We had this same issue.  Changing the App Pool Managed Pipeline to Classic solved it for us.